# Woocommerce content-single-product template override wont work

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a problem, and im struggling from yesterday with it. So, I have web with woocommerce that is still on localhost.
I have problem with template override. I overrided loop start, end, content-product.php and content-single-product.php in my theme and that works ok. 
I have problem with content-single-product.php because I want it to make dependable on category (whatever as identification - id, name, slug). So I found few solutions on google but none will work.
In my singe-product.php I replaced

```
 woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
```

with

```
if ( is_product_category( 'my-cat-slug' ) )
{
   woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-dogs'   );  
}
else {
   woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); 
}
```

I tried putting instead of my-cat-slug actual Cat Name, I tried using `!is_product_category` to get inverse... Also nothing.
Of course I put single-product.php to woocommerce folder in my theme where rest of working overridden files are. And I created file content-single-product-dogs.php where I copied content from content-single-product.php with some changes, as small as just TEST written somewehere.

Also I tried

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_content' ) ) {
    function woocommerce_content() {
        if ( has_term( 'my-cat-slug', 'product_cat' ) ) {
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-dogs' );
            endwhile;
        }
        else {
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
            endwhile;
        }
    }
}
```

That also doesn't work. Everything I use, it always falls back to default overridden content-single-product.php

I have no more ideas. Please someone help :)

P.S Is it possible to change default product-image.php that will be different for that custom content-single-product-dog.php?

Thanks

Comment: what is your version of woocommerce? `woocommerce_get_template_part` is deprecated in the current version

Comment: Thanks. Its up to date. Latest version. Aaaah so its not woocommerce_get.. but wc_get. Will try and test

Comment: use `has_term( 'my-cat-slug', 'product_cat' )` on the first attempt code.. `is_product_category` is when you are viewing a product category page... will not check if product has a category...

Comment: Thanks, also doesnt work. Hmm but when i put plain  woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-dogs' ); just by itslef so it should use content-single-product-dogs.php  it still has no effect. Its like single-product.php override is ignored.. Really wierd, its in woocommerce inside theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already **[integrate](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/)** WooCommerce in your theme, you might to **override woocommerce_content()** function.

It works perfectly on WooCommerce 2.5.5

> - Place you custom template files to **your_theme/woocommerce/**
> - Add code-snippet listed below to your theme **functions.php**:

```
/** 
 * Override 'woocommerce_content' function
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_content' ) ) {

/**
 * Output WooCommerce content.
 *
 * This function is only used in the optional 'woocommerce.php' template.
 * which people can add to their themes to add basic woocommerce support.
 * without hooks or modifying core templates.
 *
 */
function woocommerce_content() {

    if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            // Template depends from category slug
        
            if ( has_term( 'my-cat-slug', 'product_cat' ) ) {

              woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-dogs' );  

            } else {

              woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); 

            }

        endwhile;

    } else { ?>

        <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

            <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop'); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

            <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop'); ?>

        <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

            <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

        <?php endif;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, i alsready soldved this. But i marked your answer as closest. The thing was relatd to woocommerce_content, because i had woocommerce.php file root of my theme, and then woocommerce ignores single-product template... When i removed that, and edited single product, and content product to have my wanted header, and footer, and then changed loop based on category. Everything worked. Thanks