# WooCommerce:Create Custom Product template and how to Call

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

by default single-product.php will load for all the products page, but now i want to call different template on the basis of category, so let's say i have a category customize then i have created file with category slug single-product-customize.php

**Problem**  single-product-customize.php this file is returning my product as normal post view(blog page) why it's not loading on product page.

```
 <?php 
                global $post;
                $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug;

                if ( in_array( 'customize', $categories ) ) {
                  woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-customize' );
                } else {
                    woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
                } 
        ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WooCommerce - How to create multiple single product template based on category?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789472/woocommerce-how-to-create-multiple-single-product-template-based-on-category)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789472/woocommerce-how-to-create-multiple-single-product-template-based-on-category and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501746/woocommerce-single-product-template-by-categories. please research your question before posting or explain clearly why those solutions don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a template single-product.php it will be called by your products. then you can do your own coding inside that.

{posttype}-product.php is the way to create template for any post type.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you give some code example how can i implement your suggestion.. I am following this link ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35885013/woocommerce-content-single-product-template-override-wont-work/35957022

Comment: in this logic
if ( in_array( 'customize', $categories ) ) {
                  woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-customize' );
echo something to check whether it is printing only for product page or not and let me know
                } else {
                    woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
                }